# AppleScript Quick Action Services Shortcut issue - MacOS Catalina

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, automation, applescript, macos-catalina, automator

Running on: MacOS Catalina 10.15.5

I made a Quick Action in Automator and it works just fine. In fact, I've been using it for a few years. The code in the action itself is not the problem, nor is it allowing accessibility/controls in system preferences. My problem is mind-boggling to say the least and I cannot seem to figure it out and thought I'd ask the hive mind.

After making my quick action with AppleScript and making sure the 'workflow receives: no input in any application' as I normal would do, then going in and assigning the shortcut the key 'F13' in System Preferences --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts --> Services, everything seems just great.

In the application I use this shortcut in, if I hover over the application main dropdown and hover over "Services" the item is there and has a shortcut 'F13' associated with it. If I select the shortcut from the dropdown menu, it works PERFECTLY.

Here is the problem, if I hit 'F13' on my keyboard, the service is highlighted 3 times in a row (as if it thinks I clicked it three times). I have tried a number of different shortcut keys as well (as simple as: F13 and as complicated as: ⌘⌥⌃⇧N) and the shortcut keys did not yield any positive results either.

The application I am attempting to target is Avid Pro Tools. The script works just fine when I run it inside Automator, and it also runs perfectly when I select it from the services menu when the application is in the foreground as well as the background. The issue only happens when I try to use the shortcut key (which is the whole point of the script I wrote haha). It worked fine on High Sierra and Mojave, but for some reason on Catalina it is not yielding a good outcome.

I have checked everywhere and cannot seem to find why this is happening. Any insight/help would be much appreciated. This is not an AppleScripting issue. It's something with the OS that is causing a triple selection on the services menu item prior to even running the service. It does not seem to be a Key Repeater issue either.

Thanks in advance!